# Hadoop NullPointerException in my mapper class

Tags: hadoop, nullpointerexception, mapreduce

Please help:

In my mapper class I have instance variable `protected transient HashMap<String, Double> _map = null;`

I initialized this variable in my `setup(Context context)` method, also `_map` is populated with data read in from a `SequenceFile`.

setup emthod:

```
@Override
    protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
    {       
        super.setup(context);

        Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();

        _map = new HashMap<String, Double>();

        Path seqFilePath = new Path(conf.get("in"));
        Reader reader;

        try 
        {
            reader = new Reader(conf, Reader.file(seqFilePath));
            Text key = new Text();
            DoubleWritable value = new DoubleWritable();
            while (reader.next(key, value)) 
            {
                _map.put(key.toString().trim(), value.get());
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            LOGGER.error("Can't find the input path to read: " + seqFilePath, e);
        }
    }
```

`map()` method:

```
@Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        ...
        getDiscretizationLabel(...);
        ...
    }
```

In my `getDiscretizationLabel(...)` method I try to retrieve data from `_map` variable but a `NullPointerException` is throwing:

```
private void getDiscretizationLabel(String attribute, String value, String category, int bin, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
    {
        ...
        min = _map.get(attribute + "_min"); // throws NullPointerException
        max = _map.get(attribute + "_max");

        ...

    }
```

`getDiscretizationLabel(...)` throws the `NullPointerException`, so far I am not able to figure out why is that and is blocked here.

Is there a way to resolve this or a workaround? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the file isn't being loaded/found correctly.  Just as an aside, I would use a counter (group="error", name="IOException") to count the number of times the IOException is thrown in the setup() method.  It's really easy to see that count in the counter report:

```
context.getCounter("error","IOException").increment(1);
```

If you're sure that the error isn't being thrown, write an error to the logger before the try-catch block.  Use a severity of error so that you can confirm that you can find logged error messages.

Comment: Thanks Chris, you caught it! I was missing a "/" in `seqFilePath` hence `_map` is not initialized. But I never seen a construct like `counter (group="error", name="IOException")` (I am actually not quite experienced with Java). Do you have a site where has sample code of that? Thanks again!

Comment: Also, I am perplexed why the wrong file path does not be caught by the `catch` block. Maybe you already answered this question but I did not get it. Thanks.

Comment: @xiaolaidd Updated answer with counter example.  I think the catch block is catching the exception, but you're not finding the log entry with the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I did see a (`Counters: 7`) if I use a wrong path. Do you know where the log entry for mapreduce? Is it specified in configuration file? Thanks!